# How do I convert a data frame with multiple variables in rows from wide to long in R?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
Amount          person1  person2  person3 

pocketmoney     0.5        1.3     1.7

chores          3          5        2
```

How do I turn it into something like this:

```
Person     Pocketmoney   chores

person1         0.5         3

person2         1.3         5

person3         1.7         2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We may use `data.table::transpose`

```
library(data.table)
data.table::transpose(setDT(df1), make.names = "Amount",
    keep.names = 'Person')[]
```

-output

```
     Person pocketmoney chores
    <char>       <num>  <num>
1: person1         0.5      3
2: person2         1.3      5
3: person3         1.7      2
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data.frame(Person = seq_along(df1[-1]), t(df1[-1]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Amount = c("pocketmoney", "chores"), person1 = c(0.5, 
3), person2 = c(1.3, 5), person3 = c(1.7, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Sorry would you mind revisiting my question as I edited it - I definitely want a column called 'person' (may be called something else later) with person1, person2 etc. as the values.

Comment: @RosieJones tjat was my [revious version.  which I updated with 1, 2, 3, now changed back

Comment: do you know a way in which you use the 'pivot_longer' command just because I am supposed to be reshaping the data from wide to long?

Answer (score 2):

Using tidyr:

```
> df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(-Amount) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Amount, values_from = value) %>% 
    mutate(name = sub("\\D+", "", name)) # remove "person"
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  name  pocketmoney chores
  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1             0.5      3
2 2             1.3      5
3 3             1.7      2
```

Comment: Thank you! That has worked but it's just printed the results in the output rather than changing the actual data frame?

Comment: assign df1 <- df1 %>% ....

Comment: An intersting feature is names_transform: Using `df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("person"), 
               names_to= "Person", 
               values_to = "chores",
               names_transform =list(Person =parse_number)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Amount, values_from = chores)` We could avoid the mutate line, but with have to use `parse_number` which requires another package `readr`

Comment: Wait sorry this gives me a name column that's empty. I do actually want the column to be called person with 'person1' 'person2' etc. as the values

Comment: And is there another method without the 'starts with' just because I might want to do this on other data where the person1 person2 etc. might be for example, types of animal and the column name would be 'animal' not person.

Comment: Use the method posted on my answer to directly omit Amount and avoid using `starts_with`

Comment: @JilberUrbina Oh I don't want to omit it though! I want there to be a column that has literally 'person1' 'person2' etc. as values corresponding to the other columns.